# Mocked function returning "[Getter/Setter]" in jest

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I want to test a component that uses this mixin method:

```
methods: {
    getActiveTab() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, tabs => resolve(tabs[0])));
    },
...
```

I'm mocking that method like this (I'm using [jest-chrome](https://github.com/extend-chrome/jest-chrome)):

```
chrome.tabs.query.mockImplementation((opts, cb) => cb([{ 'title': 'Hello World' }]));
```

But in my component, when I do this:

```
async mounted() {
   this.activeTab = await this.getCurrentTab();
},
```

`this.activeTab` will contain `{ title: [Getter/Setter] }`. How do I force it to return the actual value?

If I do this:

```
jest.spyOn(chrome.tabs.query, 'get').mockImplementation((opts, cb) => cb([{ 'title': 'Hello World' }]));
```

I get this error:

> Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Comment: *this.activeTab will contain { title: [Getter/Setter] }. How do I force it to return the actual value?* - did you assert the actual value? It looks like console output that shouldn't be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Try to mock `getActiveTab` that way:

```
  const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
    mocks: {
      getActiveTab: jest.fn(() => { someData: 'someValue' })
    }
  })
```

**OR** simply mock `activeTab` property, I assume it is the target property you want to assert further:

```
  const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
    mocks: {
      activeTab: {
        // desired data
      }
    }
  })
```